# Changing theme results in error - Magento 2

Tags: magento2, javascript, css

To find the solution of this question :
(add to cart not working)
[Add to cart not working for configurable products on product listing page. Magento - 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/217459/add-to-cart-not-working-for-configurable-products-on-product-listing-page-magen)
I switched the theme from my custom one to Magento luma to check whether it was a theme problem or not.

After switching back again to my custom theme some js and CSS files could not be loaded 
[image]

[image]

Here is the screenshot of console:
[image]

I had used static content deploy, upgrade, flush cache etc commands after changing the theme.

```
sudo php bin/magento setup:upgrade; sudo php bin/magento cache:flush; sudo chmod -R a+wX pub; sudo chmod -R a+wX var; sudo chmod -R a+wX app; sudo chmod -R a+wX app/etc; sudo chmod -R a+wX generated; sudo php bin/magento setup:di:compile; sudo php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy; sudo php bin/magento indexer:reindex; sudo php bin/magento cache:flush; sudo chmod -R a+wX pub; sudo chmod -R a+wX var; sudo chmod -R a+wX app; sudo chmod -R a+wX app/etc; sudo chmod -R a+wX generated;
```

Also please tell me the proper way of switching between themes in Magento.

Comment: Is your files (js&css) accessible directly from the browser? It can be permission issue when magento trying to write files in the directory in which it have not permission to write files. Make sure you run all cli commands from the right user (from which web-server runs).

Comment: This is Already done